# Create Reference List Pointing to Multiple CKRecords in CloudKit

Tags: cloudkit, ckreference

*Swift 3.1, Xcode 8.3.3*

I have a record type in CloudKit called `Aircraft` and it has a field called `fieldValues` that is of type `Reference List`.

In my code, I have an `aircraft` CKRecord and several `fieldValue` CKRecords that are children of the aircraft.

How do I put all those `fieldValue` records into the `aircraft`'s reference list?

Creating a `CKReference` appears to only allow a single record in it:

```
let reference = CKReference(record: fieldValueRecord, action: .deleteSelf)
```

But I'm trying to connect many `fieldValue`s to a single `aircraft`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

*Swift 3.1, Xcode 8.3.3*

After some trial and error, I finally figured it out. It goes something like this:

```
//Parent record (Aircraft)
let recordAircraft = CKRecord(recordType: "Aircraft", recordID: ...)

//Add child references (FieldValue). As far as I know, the child records must have already been created and sent to CloudKit
var fieldValueReferences = [CKReference]()

for fieldValue in fieldValues{
  let ref = CKReference(record: fieldValue, action: .deleteSelf)
  fieldValueReferences.append(ref)
}

//Assign the array of references to the key that represents your Reference List field
recordAircraft["fieldValues"] = fieldValueReferences as CKRecordValue
```

I hope that helps someone else.